# sharedprefs not passing to BroadcastReceivers onReceive method

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

In my activity I have set some shared preferences -->

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor;
PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();

PrefsEditor.putString("contact1", contact1);
PrefsEditor.putString("contact2", contact2);
PrefsEditor.commit();
```

I can access these values from sharedpreferences from another class, so I know they have saved correctly.

My issue is , I then want to access this data from within a class that extends BroadcastReceiver (so not an activity)

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String contact1,contact2;   

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 

      SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs",      Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  contact1 = preferences.getString("contact1", "");
  contact2 = preferences.getString("contact2", "");
  Log.i(TAG, "data from shared prefs: " + contact1);
```

The logcat shows the above as "data from shared prefs: " , so nothing is received. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ? Is it the context maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: did you resister myReceiver class ??

Comment: yes, its in the manifest ... it fires the intent that I want, no sharedprefs are available though

Comment: I can't find this issue。Your code in my device is correct.

Comment: what is the value of `contact1` before you put it here:  `PrefsEditor.putString("contact1", contact1);` ?

Comment: Is your `BroadcastReceiver` class in the same package as the `Activity`?

Comment: contact1 is populated from a gcm received , like I said, all values are available from shareprefs in another activity, only failing to retrieve from inside broadcast receiver

Comment: @Gary : Did you see my question?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver is in a package called library , the activity is in a different package (main)

Comment: I have moved the broadcastreceiver into the same package as my activities ... same result

Comment: Hmmm, I'm surprised. I can understand it not working if they were in different packages but it should work if they're in the same package. The reason is when you call `getSharedPreferences(...)` for the first time, an xml file called `com.example.mypackage.myprefs.xml` (for example) is created and that's where the preferences are stored. It's as simple as that - shared preferences is just an xml file. As long as all app components calling `getSharedPreferences(...)` are in the same package, they should get access to the same xml file.